# `Segmentation fault` when running vpython

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, vpython

I'm trying to run the [vpython bounce ball demo code](http://www.vpython.org/contents/bounce_example.html). But each time I run this script the window pops up super fast and shuts down again. Then I get a `Segmentation fault`(and only that! no other info). Does anyone know how I can run Vpython properly?

**Extra info:**

Installed vpython from the Ubuntu Software Center(name package: python-visual)

OS: Ubuntu 11.10, 64 bit

Graphics driver: VESA: M92

Python version: 2.7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
sudo rm /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/fglrx/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
```

From: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-visual/+bug/787932